# Error: Binlogging on server not active when setting up Master Slave replication on one machine

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I am trying to set up Master Slave Replication on my local machine using [this tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/mysql/mysql-master-slave-replication-tutorial).

I am close to the end but when I try to run `mysqldump` using the `--master-data=2` I get an error

```
mysqldump: Error: Binlogging on server not active
```

All the solutions I've come across have said to add `log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log` to `my.cnf` which I have done and it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

This is my `my.cnf` file:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld_multi]
mysqld      = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin  = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
user        = multi_admin
password    = multipass

[mysqld2]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld_slave.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld_slave.sock
port            = 3307
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql_slave
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
server-id   = 2
relay-log   = /var/log/mysql_slave/relay-bin
relay-log-index = /var/log/mysql_slave/relay-bin.index
master-info-file = /var/log/mysql_slave/master.info
relay-log-info-file = /var/log/mysql_slave/relay-log.info
read_only   = 1

[mysqld1]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3305
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
server-id   = 1
log_bin     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog = 1
binlog-format = ROW

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Did you restarted mysql server?

Comment: Yes, several times

Comment: Heads up: sometimes, according to `ps aux`, even `service mysql restart` won't really restart the server (and therefore reload the configs), I had to run `mysqladmin shutdown` and then `service mysql start` to have it actually restart

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you abandon mysql_multi and go with the Docker solution.  This lets you have separate my.cnf files, which *may* be part of the problem.

There may even be a pair of Docker images already set up for Master and Slave.  I'm pretty sure there is for Galera clustering.

I presume you are setting up M-S on a single server just for experimentation?  Doing so for Production is virtually useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single mysql image. Use the below docker-compose file

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysqlmaster:
    image: mysql:5.7.15
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql-master:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./config/mysql-master:/etc/mysql/conf.d/
  mysqlslave:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql-slave:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./config/mysql-slave:/etc/mysql/conf.d/
  mysqlconfigure:
    image: mysql:5.7.15
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_SLAVE_PASSWORD=root"
      - "MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD=root"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
      - "MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER=repl"
      - "MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=repl"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_connector.sh:/tmp/mysql_connector.sh
    command: /bin/bash -x /tmp/mysql_connector.sh
```

**mysql_connector.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE_PATH=$(dirname $0)

echo "Waiting for mysql to get up"
# Give 60 seconds for master and slave to come up
sleep 60

echo "Create MySQL Servers (master / slave repl)"
echo "-----------------"


echo "* Create replication user"

mysql --host mysqlslave -uroot -p$MYSQL_SLAVE_PASSWORD -AN -e 'STOP SLAVE;';
mysql --host mysqlslave -uroot -p$MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD -AN -e 'RESET SLAVE ALL;';

mysql --host mysqlmaster -uroot -p$MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD -AN -e "CREATE USER '$MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER'@'%';"
mysql --host mysqlmaster -uroot -p$MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD -AN -e "GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO '$MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD';"
mysql --host mysqlmaster -uroot -p$MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD -AN -e 'flush privileges;'


echo "* Set MySQL01 as master on MySQL02"

MYSQL01_Position=$(eval "mysql --host mysqlmaster -uroot -p$MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD -e 'show master status \G' | grep Position | sed -n -e 's/^.*: //p'")
MYSQL01_File=$(eval "mysql --host mysqlmaster -uroot -p$MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD -e 'show master status \G'     | grep File     | sed -n -e 's/^.*: //p'")
MASTER_IP=$(eval "getent hosts mysqlmaster|awk '{print \$1}'")
echo $MASTER_IP
mysql --host mysqlslave -uroot -p$MYSQL_SLAVE_PASSWORD -AN -e "CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='mysqlmaster', master_port=3306, \
        master_user='$MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER', master_password='$MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD', master_log_file='$MYSQL01_File', \
        master_log_pos=$MYSQL01_Position;"

echo "* Set MySQL02 as master on MySQL01"

MYSQL02_Position=$(eval "mysql --host mysqlslave -uroot -p$MYSQL_SLAVE_PASSWORD -e 'show master status \G' | grep Position | sed -n -e 's/^.*: //p'")
MYSQL02_File=$(eval "mysql --host mysqlslave -uroot -p$MYSQL_SLAVE_PASSWORD -e 'show master status \G'     | grep File     | sed -n -e 's/^.*: //p'")

SLAVE_IP=$(eval "getent hosts mysqlslave|awk '{print \$1}'")
echo $SLAVE_IP
mysql --host mysqlmaster -uroot -p$MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD -AN -e "CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='mysqlslave', master_port=3306, \
        master_user='$MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER', master_password='$MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD', master_log_file='$MYSQL02_File', \
        master_log_pos=$MYSQL02_Position;"

echo "* Start Slave on both Servers"
mysql --host mysqlslave -uroot -p$MYSQL_SLAVE_PASSWORD -AN -e "start slave;"

echo "Increase the max_connections to 2000"
mysql --host mysqlmaster -uroot -p$MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD -AN -e 'set GLOBAL max_connections=2000';
mysql --host mysqlslave -uroot -p$MYSQL_SLAVE_PASSWORD -AN -e 'set GLOBAL max_connections=2000';

mysql --host mysqlslave -uroot -p$MYSQL_MASTER_PASSWORD -e "show slave status \G"

echo "MySQL servers created!"
echo "--------------------"
echo
echo Variables available fo you :-
echo
echo MYSQL01_IP       : mysqlmaster
echo MYSQL02_IP       : mysqlslave
```

You can get the above code from my git repo https://github.com/tarunlalwani/docker-compose-mysql-master-slave

PS: Content taken from my article at http://tarunlalwani.com/post/mysql-master-slave-using-docker/